# How to Create HTML Template with parameters in .Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, templates

I am trying to create a Report that has Header Information (e.g. Project Information) and its transactions in Detailed Information.

e.g.

Project ID: 1010    Name: Health Evaluation    Client: US Govt

Location: DC      Date: 31-Dec-2014          Contact : 000-000-0000

Detailed Transactions......

Acct No|Acct Name|Current Charges|Year-to-Date Charges|Project-to-Date Charges

100|Employee|251|1251|15427

110|Office|10|100|1221

120|Postal|5|20|200
...More

All the values come from database.

while doing some search on how to do, i found one of the best way is to create parameters html template or templates ? for both header and the detailed page and loop through it, but i am not sure how and where to start this. Could some one please give me some information / links or If you think there is a better way, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

For reports could use crystal reports. it has many advantages, could export into excel, pdf, word. and it's very easy to create reports.
works for asp.net also but I got some issues while using export and other commands, but I make it works from code and ussing buttons instead of the crystal report control.

[Use Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617988/use-crystal-report-for-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: As of now, we are using crystal reports, but its taking long time for generation as it is on ondemand report and not all managers can see everything. if we can go via html editor, the report can be generated once and stored in text file and then we can apply security in the Viewtime .